# Thread synchronization ,anyone can give me algorithm?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

My task is to write a encrypted program in C.

There is a source file and a target file.My program 
need read content from source file, encrypt them and
write encrypted content to target file.

There are 7 threads in my program.

Three threads read the source file one line by one line and put contents of file 
into a shared buffer 1, a thread reads contents from shared buffer 1, encrypts it
and puts into a shared buffer 2, and another three threads read encrypted content 
from shared buffer 2 and write it into target file.

My thinking is to create two mutices to ensure that there is just one thread can read from
source file or write to target file at same time. My problem is how can I control access by multiple threads to a shared buffer 1, shared buffer 2.  I know it is quit like a Producer/consumer problem but more complex. Anyone can give me advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gww -if it isn't, it's a very silly way to do it!

Comment: @MartinBeckett: I was thinking the same thing

Comment: in a single time we can not read write file with single thread

Comment: @GWW Yes, it's an assignment.

Comment: I suppose this isn't really trivial when you take into account the `finished` condition :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a very good example about mutex, shared memory and multi-threading communications in boost examples, [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes).

This example use a shared memory for storing messages from one tread and another one read them, blocking the shared memory for concurrent access. You can apply for your threads.

Comment: where can I apply for my threads? Also, does boost support C?

Comment: Not in C but you can study it so you can use these concepts in your C program.